# Why did Russia started war with Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, international

As you know when Russia declared war on Ukraine many countries had declared embargo on Russia.
And Russia didnt want to annex Ukraine completly or even making Ukraine Puppet.
So why is Russia declared war? Does Russia wants to start World war III?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What had the Russian government to gain from the late 2021 military build up and threatening possible invasion of Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70052/what-had-the-russian-government-to-gain-from-the-late-2021-military-build-up-and) and [What is the purpose of the siege of the Ukrainian city of Mariupol by the Russian invaders?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71699/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-siege-of-the-ukrainian-city-of-mariupol-by-the-russia)

Comment: I would guess Russia just wants to trade normally, and is clever enough to know the threats of permanent isolation are empty.

Answer (score 4):

Russian Federation would not mind making Ukraine its puppet state. Why not? At least one of the invasion plans was the regime change in Kiev to a more cooperating one, instead of occupying and holding a small piece of Ukrainian land.

Russia had some canned statesmen for Ukraine which could be used for such state, such as [Dimitriyev](https://t.me/s/russ_orientalist) who reportedly went on a trip with the Russian army from Belarus; Opposition influencer [Shariy](https://t.me/s/asupersharij); and perhaps [Medvedchuk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Medvedchuk) too.

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible answers to this question so highly opposing that seems not possible to give any neutral balance or generalization:

- Some "collective West" feeds its wealth by destroying economies of other countries, through millennia. They want to destroy economy of Russia also, and this attack is actually a defense.
- Some dictator seems reading about Peter the Great way too much, and wants to signify himself in the history by establishing the comparable empire.

It is up to every of us to choose whom to believe. I can pile up the sources on both points of view without end.

Comment: Are they really opposing? Putin may want to rebuild an Empire and protect his/his friends economic interests at the same time. Also he may want to appear strong and protective to the Russian population. After all Ukraine was their backyard and halting western influence there would show strength. And he as been spreading propaganda about Russian speakers in Ukraine being endangered, so now he has to come save them.

Comment: You can also assume that just both are true, mad dictator faces the zombie civilization. Amazing.

Comment: "Mad dictator versus the zombie civilization" is now my new band name.

Comment: Band names aside, Ukraine moving more toward the EU and out of Russia's influence negatively impacts Putin oligarch friends economic interests. (Russian economy as a whole I dont know)

Comment: What, exactly, was the West doing to Russia that forced it to attack Ukraine? Rather than say, imposing economic sanctions or seizing property (since economic relations are the main method by which the West destroys other countries)

Comment: the reconciliation between two opposing pieces of propaganda should not be a neutral balance (Hitler: "kill the Jews!" Jews: "no, don't kill us!" Centrists: "What if we compromise and only kill half?") but should rather be the truth, which could be one, the other, somewhere in between, or something else entirely. (In the aforementioned contrived example, Hitler is 100% wrong, the Jews are 100% correct and there is no need for any "balance" between the opposing sides)

Comment: @user253751 Its not about justification (none) but motivation (Ukraine's natural resources, show of power).